# Filtering through two querysets with a many to many relationship in between

Tags: django

I have 3 different models, activity, category and sector. There's a many to many relationship between category and activity, and a one to many relationship between category and sector (a category to one sector).

In a form I am getting the sector (mandatory) and I can also get the category (non mandatory field). I stock that into the session then I want to select every activities that are either in the category selected (if any selected) or in the sector.

When a category is selected it's fine I just filter activities on activities_have_category. But for the case where only sector I can't filter it properly.

I tried the solution to a quite similar problem but it didn't work...

```
Solution tried: activity.objects.filter(category__sector__sector_name =request.session['sector']['sector_name'])

Result: Cannot resolve keyword 'category' into field. Choices are: activities_have_category, activities_have_countries, activities_have_output_outcome_impact, activity_name, description, outcome_impact, output_outcome, product_service

What I would like to get in SQL:
SELECT  activity_name FROM activity WHERE activities_have_category IN (SELECT category_name FROM category WHERE category_sector = "sector selected")

class sector(models.Model):
    sector_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.sector_name

class category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    category_sector = models.ManyToManyField('sector')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.category_name


class activity(models.Model):
    activity_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()
    product_service = models.TextField()
    output_outcome = models.TextField()
    outcome_impact = models.TextField()
    activities_have_category = models.ManyToManyField('category')
    activities_have_output_outcome_impact = models.ManyToManyField('output_outcome_impact')
    activities_have_countries = models.ManyToManyField('country')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.activity_name
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the relation is `activities_have_category`, furthermore the relation of a `category` to `sector` is `category_sector`, so you should query like:

```
activity.objects.filter(
    activities_have_category__category_sector__sector_name=request.session['sector']['sector_name']
)
```

Given one can also provide a category value, you can filter like:

```
activity.objects.filter(
    activities_have_category__category_sector__sector_name=request.session['sector']['sector_name'],
    activities_have_category__category_name=category_name
)
```

I would however strongly advice to use shorter names. Usually one does *not* prefix names with the name of the model and according to PEP-8, you should use `CamelCase` for models, you also might want to create an abstract class here that pulls up common fields, like:

```
class NameDescModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
    description = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Sector(NameDescModel):
    pass


class Category(NameDescModel):
    sectors = models.ManyToManyField('Sector')


class Activity(NameDescModel):
    product_service = models.TextField()
    output_outcome = models.TextField()
    outcome_impact = models.TextField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category')
    output_outcome_impacts = models.ManyToManyField('output_outcome_impact')
    countries = models.ManyToManyField('Country')
```

Now the query will look like:

```
Activity.objects.filter(
    categories__sectors__name=request.session['sector']['sector_name'],
    category__name=category_name
)
```